# How can I be frum in a non-Jewish work enviroment?

Tags: gentiles, tznius-modesty, employment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get non-Jews to treat you with some kind of tznius?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/how-do-you-get-non-jews-to-treat-you-with-some-kind-of-tznius)

What can I say and how can I act to prevent the non-Jewish people in my company from automatically touching and grabbing at me.

I paid for a business lunch with another client, and when this man got hand-sy with me I said, "Stop grabbing at me, I don't know you this well. This is not professional." He goes around saying to people, "She doesn't like to be touched." So now I sound like a weird-o.

They automatically pat you, and I try to stand 3 feet away from them, and try to be on guard and step away, but they are quicker than me. They touch my hand or my shouolder.

Is it possible to work with non-Jews if you are trying to be frum and shomer negiah?

And then there is the other question about the infringement on my modesty with the comments. I feel they shouldn't be able to comment on me, my body parts, my walk, or anything else. The intent of the words is slimy. But maybe it is just the way they are. I am wondering about other peoples' experiences with them.